# Sequence in Schwartz space whose Fourier transform is infinite at some 'spectral point'.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform

Can we find an explicit sequence $\{f_n\}$ of unit 2-normed Schwartz functions $f_n:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$; i.e. they lie in the unit ball of $L^2(\mathbb R)$, such that for some $\omega\in \mathbb R$ the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{d}t\; \text{e}^{-i\omega t} f_n(t)=\infty. 
\end{align}
For example, for $\omega=0$, if a function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ lies in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ but does not in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, then the condition follows trivially from the fact that Schwartz space is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$. However, this is not an explicit construction of the sequence. I am interested in finding a closed form expression for each $f_n$ that satisfies the condition mentioned.

**Edit** I realize now that the fact that Schwartz space is dense, does not assure that the sequence consists of function with unit norm.

Comment: $f_n(t)= n e^{-t^2},\omega=0$. Perhaps there is a problem in your question / understanding. If $(f_n)$ converges for the Schwartz space topology then so does $(\hat{f_n})$.

Comment: @reuns thank you for your comment it made me realize that I forgot to add that I require the sequence to be of unit norm (in $L^2$). I edited my question accordingly. Also, the sequence need not to converge in the Schwartz space.

Comment: $n^{-1/2} e^{- t^2/n^2}$